# Where's windows kernel file?

Tags: windows, kernel

What computer file contains windows kernel?

is it seen in task manager process list?

if not, why?

Comment: Are you doing homework?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_kernel

Comment: @ Daniel Beck  No. Just curious why it's not seen in task manager process list.

Comment: You need to leave out the space between the `@` and the name, otherwise notifications don't work. Like this: @DanielBeck

Comment: I was just wondering. Your question could have been copied straight from a homework assignment of a computer class the way it's worded. // Regarding notifications, just check whether it autocompletes after typing e.g. `@D` // Thanks for the ping @slhck

Comment: The kernel is not in the process list because it is not a process.  (By way of dodgy analogy, when hosting a party you don't usually put yourself on the guest list.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Great analogy, actually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for in modern versions of Windows is [ntoskrnl.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_kernel).  I don't believe it shows up in Task Manager as a running process, though.

Comment: Or `ntkrnlpa.exe` if PAE is enabled. :)

Comment: @techie007 - I learned something here today, thanks!

Comment: It indeed does not show up as a process, because it isn't. Processes, as shown in Task Manager, are running in "user space" as opposed to "kernel space". Naturally, the kernel itself runs in kernel space.

Comment: It's the system process, PID 4.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Kernel is not just a single file.  It's the core of the operating system, and relies on several files in order to function.  It is not seen as a task in the task manager... because it is what organizes those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is the first code that is executed at the boot time .The bios or the bootloader does the task of loading the kernel files of the operating system present in the boot directory of the disk space where the Windows/Linux is present.
To check where it is present in your windows system, you can go to C drive  (considering it where your windows OS is present).
Then double click the Windows directory in C drive.
Double click the boot directory.
This is where kernel code of your Windows OS present.

Comment: There is no boot directory on Windows 7.

Answer (score -2):

It is there: EDD08927-9CC4-4E65-B970-C2560FB5C289
Filesystem Path: C:\Windows\System32 (Note that the Kernel has some DLL too. ntoskrnl.exe is the executeable file, which is the core of the core)
You can find it in the taskmgmt.exe on "Details" or "Processes"- it is named as "System".

Hope, I could help.

Comment: I am sorry, but you get the facts wrong.

Comment: OK, then tell me.

Comment: For instance, Task Manager's real name is taskmgr.exe, and the kernel is in several locations

Comment: "taskmgr" - yea your right i looked into it and found out i got confused (there is a "diskmgmt" and i switched the "MGMT" over to taskmanager XD)

Comment: The kernelfiles yea but the core is the executeable, which reads at booting all dll and so on to continue to boot. at very first the winload.efi then all the DLL and so on.
EDIT: DLL-Data is not a program itself, which the kernel is. You can imagine DLL-Data as "Manuals and confighelps " to build up the system at booting. :) dll - dynamic linked library btw.

Comment: The question asks for the kernel file, not the bootloader. There are several kernel files, and the most important of them is kernelbase.dll

Comment: the kernelbase.dll is also just not a program, it is a "how to build up the basekernel" manual. The Kernelfile should be in my opinion an executeable code, which activates the kernel-beeing. and all that kernelfiles you are telling from, are just dll, as i said earlier. They are part of the kernel but not the kernel himself.

Comment: so if the question is about THE KERNELFILE, it is ntoskrnl.exe. (it says OS in the name so its kinda obvious ^^)

Comment: oh and btw the bootloader is MBR - Master boot record.. not winload.efi ^^ 
winload.efi is just a script helping on booting.

Comment: Try delete the KernelBase.dll and see what happens, but don't actually do it, though. All programs need the codebase, everything is relying on it, so what is more kernel than it? Nothing.

Comment: Again, you are confusing facts, the bootloader is indded winload.efi, MBR stands for Master Boot Record, is what organizes the bootloaders

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the KernelBase.dll is the manual for building up the kernel. So no surprise why the kernel needs it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library if youre interested in ;)

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Windows_NT, NTOSKRNL.EXE is what does low-level kernel-mode executions, it is only a part of the kernel, part isn't whole, saying the kernel is NTOSKRNL.EXE is like saying fruit is apple...

Comment: @Julz - Instead of indicating you were confused in comment you should edit and clarify your answer.